# How to enable preview features for Java 14 in Eclipse 2020-12?

Tags: java, eclipse

Recently I switched to Eclipse 2020-12 with JDK-15 support. Because of a bug in JDK-15 involved in initializing JVM from an executable (still present in 15.0.2) I need to switch back to JDK-14. Eclipse has **Enable preview features for Java 15** checkbox in Java/Compiler, but when I set **Compiler compilance level** to JDK-14, this **Enable preview…** feature gets grayed out instead of changing into **… for Java 14**.

I tried to switch back to Eclipse 2020-09, but it is unable to read projects' settings from newer Eclipse.

So, does anyone know, how to enable preview features for Java **14** in Eclipse 2020-12? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Only the preview features of the highest supported Java version are supported. Which means, **Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18) supports preview features of Java 15 only**, not of Java 14.

See e.g. [following statement by Kalyan Prasad Tatavarthi, project lead of Eclipse JDT, in the description of Eclipse bug 549258](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=549258#c0):

> As we are supporting --enable-preview feature for only the latest
> release of java, [...]

Comment: Today I learnt, that Eclipse uses `ejc` Java compiler and not JDK's `javac` and that causes the impossibility of supporting **enable preview** according to compiler compilance. So many years using it, but with incorrect imagination of it :-)